# How to split dataframe text column to boolean columns

Tags: pandas, dataframe, split

I have a dataframe containing information about approximately 300 small businesses. The column `'Business_Model'` looks as follows:

```
0    B2B business to business (companies sell to co...
1    B2B business to business (companies sell to co...
2    B2B2C business to business to consumer (compan...
3    B2B business to business (companies sell to co...
4    B2C business to consumer (the final client is ...
Name: Modelo_de_Negocio, dtype: object
```

This column has dozens of unique values, as the content of each cell can be a combination of different business models (e.g. a company can operate as B2B and B2C, whereas another can be B2B, B2C and B2B2C).

I would like to transform split the data in this column into boolean columns, one for each business model, so as to obtain something like

```
display (df[[B2B, B2C, C2C, B2G, B2B2C]])

    B2B     B2C     C2C     B2G     B2B2C
0   True    False   False   False   False
1   False   True    True    True    True
2   False   False   True    False   True
3   True    False   False   False   False
4   False   True    False   False   True
```

How could I do it? If could remove the excessive text within the values of `'Business_Model'` and keep only the initials (e.g. `B2B, B2C`) I could then split it into the new boolean columns, but I don't know how to edit the string values in this column in a smart way.

Comment: Are values starting by `B` always first per each string in `Modelo_de_Negocio` column ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If values starting in column use:

```
df = pd.get_dummies(df['Modelo_de_Negocio'].str.split().str[0], dtype=bool)
print (df)
     B2B  B2B2C    B2C
0   True  False  False
1   True  False  False
2  False   True  False
3   True  False  False
4  False  False   True
```

If values are not always in start of each string use [`Series.str.findall`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.findall.html) for get all strings starting with `B` with next digits or uppercase values, then use [`Series.str.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.join.html) and [`Series.str.get_dummies`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.get_dummies.html), last convert values to boolean:

```
df = (df1['Modelo_de_Negocio'].str.findall('(B[A-Z0-9]+)')
                              .str.join('|')
                              .str.get_dummies()
                              .astype(bool))
print (df)
     B2B  B2B2C    B2C
0   True  False  False
1   True  False  False
2  False   True  False
3   True  False  False
4  False  False   True
```

Comment: Thank you, the second code line really saved my day